# Join and Update View SQL

Tags: mysql

I have created a view and want to modify it. This view allows you to retrieve information about a chat I am developing.

In my view, I recover the messages via the identifier of the transmitter "from_id" and the identifier of the receiver "to_id". I would also like to add the username of the sender in a "from_username" field and that of the receiver in a "to_username" field.

Unfortunately I don't see any solutions because I don't know this SQL syntax at all.

```sql
select
    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`id` AS `chat_id`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`date` AS `chat_date`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`message` AS `chat_message`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`attachment` AS `chat_attachment`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`etat` AS `chat_etat`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`reply_to` AS `reply_to`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat_from`.`from_id` AS `from_id`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat_from`.`type` AS `from_type`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat_to`.`to_id` AS `to_id`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat_to`.`type` AS `to_type`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat_projet`.`projet_id` AS `projet_id`,
    `cekomecrm`.`chat_projet`.`task_id` AS `task_id`,
    `cekomecrm`.`users`.`username` AS `to_username`,
    `cekomecrm`.`users`.`username` AS `from_username`
from
    (
        (
            (
                `cekomecrm`.`chat`
                join `cekomecrm`.`chat_from` on(
                    (
                        `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`id` = `cekomecrm`.`chat_from`.`chat_id`
                    )
                )
            )
            join `cekomecrm`.`chat_to` on(
                (
                    `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`id` = `cekomecrm`.`chat_to`.`chat_id`
                )
            )
        )
        join `cekomecrm`.`chat_projet` on(
            (
                `cekomecrm`.`chat`.`id` = `cekomecrm`.`chat_projet`.`chat_id`
            )
        )
        join `cekomecrm`.`users` on(
            (
                `cekomecrm`.`chat_from`.`from_id` = `cekomecrm`.`users`.`id` AND 
                `cekomecrm`.`users`.`to_username` = `cekomecrm`.`users`.`username`
            )
        )
        join `cekomecrm`.`users` on(
            (
                `cekomecrm`.`chat_to`.`to_id` = `cekomecrm`.`users`.`id` AND 
                `cekomecrm`.`users`.`from_username` = `cekomecrm`.`users`.`username`
            )
        )
    )
```

Here is a screenshot of my view.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my view]

What I find odd is that when I created my view, I absolutely did not use this syntax. I would like to know how it works and if it is possible to do what I want.

Comment: What does your table structures look like? Right now I kinda have to reverse engineer your SQL to get an idea, and since you seem unfamiliar with the SQL you provided, I'd rather not leave things to chance, but be certain so that I can provide an  adequate answer. So, table names and fields would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have solved my problem, I will write a complete answer for the people who are likely to have this problem. I am indeed not familiar with SQL, I am still learning.

Comment: Alright, good job!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by restructuring my view.

In my case, I needed to differentiate between users who send a message and users who receive a message by identifying them using their id.

For that, I had to make a join.
The problem I encountered is that I have a users table with a username field and that to make several joins with the same field I had to differentiate it with an alias.

So what looks like this.

```sql
FROM chat
    INNER JOIN users AS uto ON uto.id = chat_to.to_id
    INNER JOIN users AS ufrom ON ufrom.id = chat_from.from_id
```

Now that I have differentiated but two joins with the same fields (here id of my users table) it is enough that I select it with their alias name like this.

```sql
SELECT
    uto.username AS to_username,
    ufrom.username AS from_username
```

And so my full view looks like this.

```sql
CREATE VIEW ViewProjet_chat AS
SELECT
    chat.id AS chat_id,
    chat.date AS chat_date,
    chat.message AS chat_message,
    chat.attachment AS chat_attachment,
    chat.etat AS chat_etat,
    chat.reply_to AS reply_to,
    chat_from.from_id AS from_id,
    chat_from.type AS from_type,
    chat_to.to_id AS to_id,
    chat_to.type AS to_type,
    chat_projet.projet_id AS projet_id,
    chat_projet.task_id AS task_id,
    uto.username AS to_username,
    ufrom.username AS from_username

FROM chat
INNER JOIN chat_from ON chat.id = chat_from.chat_id
INNER JOIN chat_to ON chat.id = chat_to.chat_id
INNER JOIN chat_projet ON chat.id = chat_projet.chat_id
INNER JOIN users AS uto ON uto.id = chat_to.to_id
INNER JOIN users AS ufrom ON ufrom.id = chat_from.from_id
```

I don't know if this is the best practice being an apprentice in SQL but now I can differentiate between sending and receiving users.